# Issue with ADSI script not pulling users from all groups

Tags: powershell, adsi

I have a list of groups that i need to pull back all users. I am aware due to the numbers it is restricted. I have tried adding page size but it does not work.
Here is the code

```
Get-Module ActiveDirectory - ErrorAction silentlycontinue
Function resolve-group}
         param ($group)
         For each ($member in $group.member){
        $obj = [ADSI] ("LDAP://" + member)
        if (obj.objectclass[1] -eq 'group'){resolve-group $obj}
        else {
                If ($obj.employeeid.length -eq 6)
{
                   $displayname = $obj.displayname
                   $employeeid = $obj.employeeid
                   $groupname = $group.name
                   $global:members +="$employeeid,$displayname,$groupname"
            }
       }
   }
}

$global:members =@()

$group = [ADSI] "LDAP://cn=ab,ou=cd,ou=ef,DC=gh,DC=BB"
resolve-group $group

$group = [ADSI] "LDAP://cn=aa,ou=cc,ou=ef,DC=gh,DC=BB"
resolve-group $group

"ID,Name,Group" > c:\test\groups.csv
$global:members | sort-object - unique >> c:\test\groups.csv
```

I don't know how to amend the script to add and increase the page size?

I have only listed a couple of the groups but there are 100's of groups
Thanks

Comment: Please [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63509966/edit) the typos in the code (we can help you with formatting it nicely after)

Comment: Why are you using ADSI, vs the AD cmdlets to make this easier on yourself? [ADDS limits the number of objects returned by design](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/ads-1000-object-limit/) until you change that setting.

Comment: HI Using the AD cmdlets took too long to run where the adsi took a quarter of the time

Comment: So how can i amend this and still return all the users?